# Duplicate registration endpoint when user reinstall the app in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-messaging, amazon-sns

Here is how I register the SNS account in android , it works fine

```
    if (gs.settings.getString("endpoint_arn", "").equals("")) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
        asnsc = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(Constant.id,Constant.secret));
        asnsc.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
        asnsc.setEndpoint("sns.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");

        new AsyncTask() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground(final Object... params) {
                try {
                    CreatePlatformEndpointRequest per = new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest();
                    String token = gcm.register(Constant.projectID);
                    Log.d("test1",""+token);
                    per.setToken(token);
                    per.setPlatformApplicationArn(Constant.platformARN);
                    CreatePlatformEndpointResult result = asnsc.createPlatformEndpoint(per);
                    gs.editor.putString("endpoint_arn",result.getEndpointArn()).commit();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                enterApp(1000); // assume 1000 ms for register GCM
            }

        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```

The problem is , when the user re-install the app, a new token is generate , and the new endpoint is create , so there is duplicate endpoint, and when I send the message in my backend , the message received several time, isn't the token will become invalid when I uninstall the app? but in my case it is still valid and how to fix it?

Comment: I use a pure GCM implementation, but for what it's worth, you may want to look at the Java code [here](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS). It checks for an existing endpoint differently (using a try-catch `GetEndpointAttributesRequest`) that creates the endpoint if a `NotFoundException` was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get a standard `uuid` created from device hardware to identify every device. and use this `uuid` as key on your backend to avoid `received several time`.

something like :

```
String id = //get mac address or IMEI from system
UUID uuid = UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(id.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
```

Comment: You should always avoid hardware identifiers in mobile apps:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#tenets_of_working_with_android_identifiers

Answer (score 0):

The GCM registration doesn't change if you re install Android app, I think you may want to add logic on your back end to see if device has already registered with SNS.

Comment: i just record the device id, don't know whether it is standard way

Comment: Why not check wether exists before registering, so you basically call your backend i.e. `isSNSRegistered` and the backend returns `true` or `false` depending on whether the device is registered you can then either return existing endpoint or register a new endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid re-creating a new endpoint arn from the same app, device and attributes. Try **saving the endpoint arn** generated first time to a **permanent storage** (securely may be on a server or sd card location) from where you can retrieve it even after app is re installed.

When the app is reinstalled, get your latest token. Call GetEndpointAttributes for the endpoint arn that was last saved and check if the token is not the latest, update it as mentioned in the psuedocode from this [link](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx223MJB0XKV9RU/Mobile-token-management-with-Amazon-SNS)

```
retrieve the latest token from the mobile OS
if (endpoint arn not stored)
    # first time registration
    call CreatePlatformEndpoint
    store returned endpoint arn
endif

call GetEndpointAttributes on the endpoint arn 

if (getting attributes encountered NotFound exception)
    #endpoint was deleted 
    call CreatePlatformEndpoint
    store returned endpoint arn
else 
    if (token in endpoint does not match latest) or 
        (GetEndpointAttributes shows endpoint as disabled)
        call SetEndpointAttributes to set the 
                     latest token and enable the endpoint
    endif
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an identifier by device and installation as a token for SNS to avoid problems.

You can check how to get it here:
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html#working_with_instance_ids_&_guids